# How to use the ↑ key in tcl to display multiple rows of history

Tags: tcl, tclsh

I first defined a multi-line function in tcl

```
tclsh8.5 [~/Desktop]proc myproc {arg1 arg2} {
>    # do something here, e.g.
>    puts [list arg1 $arg1 arg2 $arg2]
>}
```

When I want to load the history with ↑ key, I found that it can only load one line at a time, and it can't display multiple lines of history at once.

Is there any way to display the entire multi-line history when I click the ↑ key?

Comment: Maybe if you use tclreadline or rlwrap?

Comment: tclreadline will only display one line at a time, at least mine does

Comment: At the moment, I use tkcon because of this sort of thing (and I'm on Windows, where the console is a bit more finicky).